# Derive the Minimum value in the pandas dataframe and its respective column derivation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
data = np.array([[10,50,75,'test1','test2','test3'], 
                 [1000,500,175,'test1','test2','test3'], 
                 [500,50,750,'test1','test2','test3'], 
                 [1,500,5,'test1','test2','test3'],
                [50,500,15,'test1','test2','test3']]) 


df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['distance_1', 'distance_2','distance_3', 'distance_1_rep', 'distance_2_rep', 'distance_3_rep'])
df.distance_1 = df.distance_1.astype('int64')
df.distance_2 = df.distance_2.astype('int64')
df.distance_3 = df.distance_3.astype('int64')
```

I am finding the minimum distance between distance_1,2,3 colmns using

```
df['min_distance'] = df[['distance_1','distance_2','distance_3']].min(axis=1)
```

[image]

now I want to derive another column:

which gives the distance_1_rep or distance_2_rep or distance_3_rep values corresponding to the minimum values of distance_1, distance_2, distance_3

for the output the values should be

`[test1,test3,test2,test1,test3]`

How would I derive it?

Answer (score 2):

This is essentially a `lookup` problem where we first select the `distance` columns then find the index of minimum values by using `argmin` along `axis=1` , then using these indices lookup the values in the corresponding `_rep` like columns

```
c = df.filter(regex='distance_\d+$')
df['new_col'] = df[c.columns + '_rep'].values[df.index, c.values.argmin(1)]
```

---

```
   distance_1  distance_2  distance_3 distance_1_rep distance_2_rep distance_3_rep new_col
0          10          50          75          test1          test2          test3   test1
1        1000         500         175          test1          test2          test3   test3
2         500          50         750          test1          test2          test3   test2
3           1         500           5          test1          test2          test3   test1
4          50         500          15          test1          test2          test3   test3
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to use np.where for column selection based on condition:

```
np.where(df.min_distance==df.distance_1, df.distance_1_rep,
         np.where(df.min_distance==df.distance_2, df.distance_2_rep,
                  df.distance_3_rep)
         )
```

Which returns you pd.Series object with proper distance_x_rep choices according to condition. If you have many columns and the representation are not constant, embedding this into the function that takes dataframe, list of conditions and list of representations and runs recursively may be preferable option.

Something like:

```
def representations(df, list_of_conditions, list_of_repr):
#list of repr should have len longer by 1 than list of conditions
if list_of_conditions:
    return np.where(list_of_conditions[0], df[list_of_repr[0]],
                    representations(df, list_of_conditions[1:], list_of_repr[1:]))
else:
    return df[list_of_repr[0]]
```